# SQL - Insert into multiple entries without duplicates by using only one request

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

What I am trying to do :

- Inside an existing table: 'users'.
- Insert one new entry if the entry doesn't exists yet.

---

What I have tried so far in PHP :

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `NAME`, `CREATIONDATE`)
SELECT NULL, '$name', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT users.NAME FROM users
   WHERE users.NAME = '$name'
)
```

This piece of code works; I got new entries without duplicates.

---

The problem is :

To be more clean and save the number of request, I would like to build only one request to avoid executing `X INSERT INTO` inside a PHP loop.

E.g:

```
foreach ( $list as $name )
{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `NAME`, `CREATIONDATE`)";
   $sql .="SELECT NULL, '$name', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM users
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT users.NAME FROM users
       WHERE users.NAME = '$name'
   )
   );
   $rq = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );
   $rq->execute ();
 }
```

Comment: Why not use Insert ignore into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use UNIQUE constraint on the column NAME and do the below query

> INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `NAME`, `CREATIONDATE`) values ( 1, name1,
>   1-2-3), (2, name2, 1-2-3), (3, name3, 1-2-3)

This query will be atomic. That means, if there is violation of integrity constraint, none of the rows will be inserted

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for your answer. In fact your solution is working but the new problem is, as you just say, even my PHP try to add, for example, 100 lines, if only one is new inside the 100, the whole request is rejected...So close!

Comment: Oh yes I just found the solution, I just mix your solution with the comment from Farhan Qasim and it works. (UNIQUE INDEX on name + INSERT IGNORE INTO)

Comment: Glad to know you found your solution